# Python syntax error 2.7.4

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got syntax error for the code below. Why is song not being considered as an attribute?

```
class MyStuff(object):
  def _ini_(self):
    self.song = "Hey Brother"
  def apple(self):
    print "I got a iphone"

music = MyStuff()
music.apple()
print music.song
```

ERROR:

```
I got a iphone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in 
    print music.song
AttributeError: 'MyStuff' object has no attribute 'song'
```

Comment: There is *no syntax error* here.

Comment: `'_ini_' != '__init__'`

Comment: I made the change but still getting error: AttributeError: 'MyStuff' object has no attribute 'song'

Comment: Works fine here. You must have copied Martijn's code incorrectly. The initialiser must be named precisely right to get called automatically.

Comment: @user3409814: did you use **double** underscores before and after the name?

Answer (score 3):

You misnamed the method initializer:

```
def _ini_(self):
```

will **not** be called automatically when creating your instance. As a result, the `song` attribute is never created, trying to access it later leads to the `AttributeError` exception.

Name it `__init__`:

```
class MyStuff(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.song = "Hey Brother"
    def apple(self):
        print "I got a iphone"
```

Note the *double* underscores before and after the word `init`.

Demo:

```
>>> class MyStuff(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.song = "Hey Brother"
...     def apple(self):
...         print "I got a iphone"
... 
>>> music = MyStuff()
>>> music.apple()
I got a iphone
>>> print music.song
Hey Brother
```